# Recorrer varias veces un fichero para hacer una conexion FTP

Tags: python, archivo, login, bucle-for

Necesito recorrer el archivo `login.txt` varias veces, tantas veces como usarios tenga (en este caso solo tengo un usuario)

```
with open("login.txt") as fichero:
    dirServer = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
    usuario = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
    passwd = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()

# Se crea una instancia de dicha clase. Toma como argumentos host, user, passwd
ftp = FTP(dirServer)

# Hacemos el login de usuario y passwd, 
ftp.login(user=usuario, passwd=passwd)

# La función FTP.cwd() es utilizada para cambiar de directorio o carpeta
ftp.cwd("zzz") 

# Retorna información sobre los archivos y carpetas en la ubicación actual.
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

# Ejecuta el comando RETR para descargar el archivo README en modo binario.
# El segundo parámetro es una función callback que será llamada por cada bloque de bytes recibidos,
# que a su vez estos son pasados como argumento a dicha función. En este caso se pasa la función write de un objeto file
ftp.retrbinary('RETR prueba.txt', open('PruebaFtp.txt', 'wb').write)

# cerramos la conexion
ftp.quit()
```

El formato del archivo `login.txt` es:

```
dirServer: 10.0.0.4
usuario: pepito
passwd: ****
```

Ahora el archivo es el siguiente `login.txt`

```
dirServer: 10.0.0.4
usuario: pepito
passwd: ****
dirServer: 10.0.0.4
usuario: donpinpon
passwd: ****
dirServer: 10.0.0.4
usuario: donpinpon
passwd: ****
```

No sé recorrerlo, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Sería recomendable que en vez de una imagen pongas el codigo pasteado.

Comment: Formatea correctamente el código http://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: Código formateado, Soy nuevo y no me enteraba muy bien como hacerlo. Ya si se hacerlo para futuras consultas. Disculpen las molestias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta que repitas en bucle el mismo código que has usado, y que salgas del bucle cuando ya no haya más datos que leer, lo cual detectarás porque `readline()` te devuelve una línea "vacía".

Algo así:

```
with open("login.txt") as fichero:
    while True:   # Repetir por siempre (o hasta que salgamos con break)
        linea = fichero.readline()
        if not linea:   # Si leemos linea vacia, salimos del bucle
            break
        # En caso contrario, separamos el dato y hacemos lo mismo con las dos lineas siguientes
        dirServer = linea.split(":")[1].strip()
        linea = fichero.readline()
        usuario = linea.split(":")[1].strip()
        linea = fichero.readline()
        passwd = linea.split(":")[1].strip()

        # El resto sigue como lo tenías, accediendo por ftp 
        # según los datos que acabamos de leer
        ftp = FTP(dirServer)
        ftp.login(user=usuario, passwd=passwd)
        ftp.cwd("zzz") 
        ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR prueba.txt', open('PruebaFtp.txt', 'wb').write)
        ftp.quit()
```

Comment: Perfecto muchisimas gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
#libreria para mejorar la visualizacion de arreglos
from pprint import pprint

#abrimos el archivo
with open("ts.txt") as f:
    # leemos linea por linea del archivo solo si no esta vacia
    # y la asignamos a un arreglo r
    r = [ x.split(":")[1].strip()  for x in f if x.strip()]

#imprimimos los 3 primeros elementos
print("primeros 3 elementos: {0} {1} {2} \n".format(r[0],r[1],r[2]) )

#imprimimos todo el arreglo
print("arreglo completo:")
pprint(r)
```

resultado:

```
primeros 3 elemntos: 10.0.0.4 pepito ****

arreglo completo:
['10.0.0.4',
 'pepito',
 '****',
 '10.0.0.4',
 'donpinpon',
 '****',
 '10.0.0.4',
 'donpinpon',
 '****']
```

Comment: Perfecto bryro, funciona correctamente, aún asi me surge una duda, si yo tengo dos usuarios y se conectan a servidor via Ftp y hacen una descarga, debería tener dos descargas y tengo una sola. ¿He cometido algún error?

Comment: puedes hacer un for in range(0, len(r) /3): una conexion por cada 3 datos osea ip usuario y password..
y para mejorar la eficiencia utiliza hilos ejemplo: https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/12/threading-programacion-con-hilos-i.html